# A surjective ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am reading [P. E. Frenkel, *Simple proof of Chebotarev's theorem on roots of unity*](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0312398v2). The proof of Lemma 1 claims the following.

> 1. Function
>    $$Z[\Omega] \rightarrow Z[\Omega]/(1 − \Omega, p) = F_p,\quad \Omega \rightarrow 1$$ is a surjective ring homomorphism.
> 2. Therefore, the latter homomorphism factors through the former one via a surjective homomorphism $Z[ω]\rightarrow F_p$ whose kernel is
>    the ideal $$(1 − \Omega, p)/(\Phi_p(\Omega)) = (1−\omega, p) = (1−ω),$$

I do not see these equalities, and the surjectivity is thus not obvious either. I do not know what $(\cdot, \cdot)$ here means. Is $\Omega\rightarrow 1$ supposed to be an evaluation homomorphism?

I am sure it is obvious to someone who is versed in abstract algebra. I would appreciate the elucidation.

Answer (score 1):

$(a,b)$ is the ideal generated by $a$ and $b$.

1. It is just a composite of two surjective morphisms:

- the evaluation ${\bf Z}[\Omega]\to{\bf Z}[\Omega]/(1−\Omega)={\bf Z},\quad \Omega\mapsto1$;
- the "mod p" morphism: ${\bf Z}\to{\bf Z}/(p)={\bf F}_p$.

2. 

- The first equality is a restriction (to ideals) of the equality of rings ${\bf Z}[\Omega]/(1+\Omega+\dots+\Omega^{p-1})={\bf Z}[\omega]$ which constitutes the definition of $\omega$.
- The second equality is because modulo $1-\omega$, we have $\omega^k\equiv1$ ($\forall k$), hence $$p=1+1+\dots+1\equiv1+\omega+\dots+\omega^{p-1}=0,$$so $p\in(1-\omega)$.
- The fact that the morphism $w:{\bf Z}[\Omega]\to{\bf F}_p$ (of 1.) "factors" through the canonical morphism $u:{\bf Z}[\Omega]\to{\bf Z}[\omega]$ via some morphism $v:{\bf Z}[\omega]\to{\bf F}_p$ (i.e. $w=v\circ u$) is due to the inclusion $\ker u\subset\ker w$, i.e. $$(1+\Omega+\dots+\Omega^{p-1})\subset(1−\Omega,p).$$ This is because $$p\equiv1+\Omega+\dots+\Omega^{p-1}\bmod{1-\Omega}$$ (by the same trick as above for $\omega$).
- This new morphism $v$ is surjective because the morphism $v\circ u=w$ is.
- Finally, since $u$ is surjective, $\ker v=u(\ker w)=u(1−\Omega,p)=(1−\Omega,p)/(1+\Omega+\dots+\Omega^{p-1}).$

Comment: Thank you very much. I added one more item to the question. I would really appreciate it if you would elucidate that as well.

Comment: Could you please explain more of your third bullet point? Presumably we are to find $v$. I understand the inclusion relation ker $u \subset$ ker $w$. I can see naively by way of elementary fraction the necessity of introducing $(1-\Omega, p)/(\Phi_p(\Omega))$. But what is the formal proof of it?

Comment: I do not understand the end of your comment (after "I can see naively"). As for the beginning, if you understand that ker u⊂ ker w, you are done: define $v$ by $v(y)=w(x)$ for any of the $x$'s such that $y=u(x)$.

Comment: Never mind the sentence "I can see naively". I do not see how your first bullet point under point 2 deduces "$(1 − \Omega, p)/(\Phi_p(\Omega)) = (1−\omega, p)$". Could you please explain? Your first bullet point under point 2 seems just a restatement of the first surjective ring homomorphism at the bottom of page 1 of the original paper.

Comment: The kernel of that surjective ring homomorphism $u:{\bf Z}[\Omega]\to{\bf Z}[\omega],\,\Omega\mapsto\omega$ is the ideal generated by $\Phi_p(\Omega)=1+\Omega+\dots+\Omega^{p-1},$ and $u$ sends the ideal $(1-\Omega,p)$ onto the ideal $(1-\omega,p).$

Comment: @Hans, are you finally [satisfied with my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: I am preoccupied and away from this problem for a bit. I need some time to come back to think through your answer. Thank you, Anne.